# Calculus - Derivative

Tags: calculus

A printer has a contract to print 200 000 copies of a small catalogue. It costs $\text_{$8/h}$ to run the printing press, which will produce 1200 impressions per hour. Each impression prints x catalogues, x being the number of plates (metal copies of the set type) that are used on the press. Each plate costs $2. How many plates should be made so that the job is done most economically?

Comment: The equation that determines the cost is    1200hx =200 000, where cost = 8h + 2*x.  Minimize the second equation maybe?

Comment: Does x stands for the number of catalogues (per impression) and for the number of plates ?

Answer (score 1):

So first of all you have 2 equations:
$1200hx = 200000$ and $P = 8h +2x$
where $P$ is the cost.

Substitute and take derivative.

$\begin{align}P(x) = \dfrac{4000}{3x} + 2x \\
P'(x)= \dfrac{-4000}{3x^2} + 2\\
\end{align}$

Now minimize
$0 = \dfrac{-4000}{3x^2} + 2$ at $x \approx26 $
and since $P''(26) > 0 $ the function is minimized 
so $ x = 26$